# Hide Docker Volumes

Tags: linux, docker, udev, file-manager

I decided to use a partition for all things docker.

Everything went smooth and working as expected. Except one part. When I boot up a project which uses "volumes" it shows it in the file manager. If I boot up multiple projects, it starts to get annoying.

[image: the-problem]

I tried using udev rules; `/etc/udev/rules.d/00-docker.rules` using [this as template](https://github.com/moby/moby/blob/7ae5222c72cc2aac42225df8f62c2f71a1813ab4/contrib/udev/80-docker.rules).

```
# hide docker's loopback devices from udisks, and thus from user desktops
SUBSYSTEM=="block", ENV{DM_NAME}=="docker-*", ENV{UDISKS_PRESENTATION_HIDE}="1", ENV{UDISKS_IGNORE}="1"
SUBSYSTEM=="block", DEVPATH=="/devices/virtual/net*", ATTR{loop/backing_file}=="/media/user/work/docker/*", ENV{UDISKS_PRESENTATION_HIDE}="1", ENV{UDISKS_IGNORE}="1"
```

Unfortunately this didn't do the trick.

It looks like their location is;
`/media/user/work/docker/overlay-2/{random characters}/merged`

I would like to ignore any "device" found under /media/user/work/docker/ to hide it from file manager. Anyway to get this straight?

Comment: I am having same issue. This started happening to be when I moved to Fedora 37. It was working fine when I was on Fedora 36. Any help?