# Hide docker mounts from udisks / file explorer

Tags: linux, docker, overlayfs, udisks

Recently, I moved my docker data from `/var/lib/docker` to the home directory: `/home/me/data/docker`. Since then, I see mounted storages in my file explorer (Nemo).

[image]

I've tried to google for `udisks` rules to hide these mounts but without success.

Could you help, please?

P.S. I see one [unanswered question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/621937/hide-docker-volumes), info from there didn't help, too.

Comment: You can't hide the mounts from your file explorer or any program for that matter (excepting namespaces). You need to configure your file explorer to ignore these mounts. I found this forum post: https://forums.linuxmint.com/viewtopic.php?t=311399

Comment: Thanks, @jrpear, but this is for mounted disks. In my case, it's about virtual devices that I have no control over the 'Disks' program.